# Is there a way to call specific classes based on a variable?

Tags: python, class

I want a program to call a specific class based on a parameter/variable value. However, I don't want to use any clunky if-statements. My first thought was to use the `globals()` function, but I couldn't get it to work. Here's an example:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__():
        print("Hello, world!")

class OtherClass:
    def runClass(className):
        # Call class based on variable className
```

The reason I want to do this is because there is a wide variety of classes may need to be called, and so just piling up if-statements in my code won't do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `my_class_instance = globals()[className]()` should do it.

Comment: Do these classes inherit from a common base class? You can't just call anything that happens to be in the global namespace and expect it to work. Similarly, can these classes be in multiple modules? Would you want to instanciate, for instance,`mymodule.MyClass`?

Comment: And what do you mean by "call a class"? Instantiating and calling a class is `SomeClass()()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can call a class via `globals`

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hello, world!")

    def __call__(self):
        return "SomeClass called"

class OtherClass:
    def runClass(self, className):
        globals()[className]()()
        
o = OtherClass()
result = o.runClass("SomeClass")
print(result)
```

Notice, I am instantiating and then calling it via the `__call__` special method, which is the closest match to your description I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict.

```
name_to_class = dict(some=SomeClass,
                     other=OtherClass)

def factory(name):
    klass = name_to_class(name)
    return klass()

some_obj = factory("some")
other_obj = factory("other")
```

Comment: So, should I create a key for each class I'd need to use? Not complaining, just need clarification.

Comment: Yes, that's one approach. You said you wanted to call a class based on a variable value, which is a bit vague. Without `if`. Well, `name` is a variable, and "some" is a value it can take on. If you have other requirements, you will need to spell them out. (Note that there _can_ be structure in the key names, like `f"{foo}-{bar}"`.) The `globals()` dict already exists, but being able to invoke _any_ class might leave things a bit open ended, inviting maintenance issues. Maybe mark certain classes with an app-specific attribute, to declare that they are participating. And then there's unit tests

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to use a dictionary to map the values of the variable className to the corresponding class.

Try this exemple :
class SomeClass:
def **init**(self):
print("Hello, world!")

class OtherClass:
def **init**(self):
print("Goodbye, world!")

classNameToClass = {
"SomeClass": SomeClass,
"OtherClass": OtherClass
}

def runClass(className):
# Call class based on variable className
cls = classNameToClass[className]
return cls()

runClass("SomeClass")  # prints "Hello, world!"
runClass("OtherClass")  # prints "Goodbye, world!"

Here, the dictionary classNameToClass maps the string names of the classes (e.g. "SomeClass") to the corresponding class objects (e.g. SomeClass). Then, in the runClass function, we look up the class object using the value of the className variable, and call it to create an instance of the class.

Comment: once you have a dictionary that maps the values of the className variable to the corresponding class, you can use this dictionary to call the appropriate class without using any if statements. Here is an example of how you could do this:

Comment: you need to work on formatting in your answer. the way it is formatted is not exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer. The parameter that governs the called class can just be assigned elsewhere. At first, I thought it would need some complex function, but in reality, I guess the question didn't give enough details. The class itself only uses items from whatever object is given. So, instead of having to dynamically call a class, it's as simple as:

```
class SomeClass:
    def printHelloWorld():
        print("Hello, world!")

class OtherClass:
    def __init__(self, usingClass):
        self.object = usingClass

    def doThis():
        usingClass.printHelloWorld()

x = OtherClass(SomeClass())
x.doThis()
```

It's on me for not giving enough information. Thank you all for your help.